# Arduino Uno cant be powered by VIN pin

Tags: arduino-uno, power

Im trying to power an Arduino Uno from a pack of 8 AA batteries (so 12V) and it just doesn't turn on. When I connect the barrel jack, it works! Any idea why the VIN doesn't work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: VIN pin should be connected directly to barrel jack. Could you test if they are connected in your Uno?

Comment: @AleksejVasinov Actually there's a diode in the + of the barrel jack connection, so it's not directly connected. A simple continuity test may fail if not done right.

Comment: I have known some inferior Chinese clones to use sub-par headers with bad connections in them. Try connecting to the pin underneath the board where the VIN is soldered.